# Derivative of log-likelihood function for Gaussian distribution with parameterized variance

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, estimation-theory

Suppose we have a parameter $\theta \in R^{n}$ that defines some noisy observation $z=\mu(\theta)+\eta, z\in R^{m}$ where the noise follows a Gaussian distribution whose covariance is a function of the parameter, i.e. $\eta\sim N(0,\Sigma(\theta))$. Then the observation random variable is $z \sim N(\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))$. Assume observations of $z$ are iid and $\Sigma=diag(\sigma_1^{2}(\theta), \sigma_2^{2}(\theta)...\sigma_m^{2}(\theta))$, where $\sigma_i^{2}\ne\sigma_j^{2}$.

Then, the log-likelihood function would be:

\begin{align}
L_z\left(z;\theta\right)&=log\left(\prod^m_{j=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma_j^2\left(\theta\right)}} e^{-\frac{\left(z_j-\mu_j(\theta)\right)^2}{2 \sigma_j^2\left(\theta\right)}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{m} -\frac{1}{2}log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2} log(\sigma_{j}^{2}(\theta))-\frac{(z_j-\mu_j(\theta))^{2}}{2\sigma_j^{2}(\theta)}\\
\end{align}

The first derivative of the log-likelihood function w.r.t the parameters would be:

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}= \sum_{j=1}^{m}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_j^2(\theta)\right)^{-1} \frac{\partial \sigma_j^2}{\partial \theta}-(z_j-\mu_j(\theta)) \frac{\partial \mu_j}{\partial \theta}\left(\sigma_j^2(\theta)\right)^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_j^2(\theta)\right)^{-2} (z_j-\mu_j(\theta))^2 \frac{\partial \sigma_j^2(\theta)}{\partial \theta}
\end{aligned}

What I'm getting confused about is: how would the log-likelihood function derivative be zero at the parameter value, when the first term of the derivative does not depend on $(z_j-\mu_j(\theta))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\th\theta\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\p\partial\newcommand\ol\overline$There is no reason to get confused here. Indeed, that "the first term of the derivative does not depend on $(z_j-\mu_j(\theta))$" does not at all prevent the derivative from taking the zero value.

If e.g. $\mu(\th)=\th$ and $\si_i(\th)=\th$ for all real $\th>0$ and all $i=1,\dots,m$, then
$$\frac{\p L}{\p\th}=-\frac n{\th^3}\,(-\ol{z^2}+\th\ol z+\th^2),$$
where $\ol z:=\frac1m\,\sum_{i=1}^m z_i$ and $\ol{z^2}:=\frac1m\,\sum_{i=1}^m z_i^2$, so that $\frac{\p L}{\p\th}=0$ at a real $\th>0$ if and only if
$$\th=\hat\th:=\hat\th_m:=\frac{-\ol z+\sqrt{\ol z^2+4\ol{z^2}}}2.$$

Moreover, here $\hat\th$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\th$. Using (say) the law of large numbers, one can easily check that $\hat\th_m$ is consistent: $\hat\th_m\to\th$ in probability as $m\to\infty$ (assuming that $\th$ is the true value of the parameter).

Comment: By the "first term", I mean $-\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_j^{2}(\theta))^{-1}\frac{\partial \sigma_j^{2}(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ in the summation. It is confusing (or unclear) to me because if I rewrite the log-likelihood function as: 
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}= \sum_{j=1}^{m}-\frac{1}{2\sigma_j^2(\theta)} \frac{\partial \sigma_j^2}{\partial \theta}\left[ 1 + \frac{(z_j-\mu_j(\theta))^2}{\sigma_j^2(\theta)} \right]-\frac{(z_j-\mu_j(\theta))}{\sigma_j^2(\theta)}\frac{\partial \mu_j}{\partial \theta}$
it is not immediately clear to me that it would be zero for any covariance function.

Comment: @JNL : Does my answer clear your confusion? If not, why not, specifically?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it has cleared the confusion I have. I can see how the LL function derivative will be zero in your answer. But that considers $\sigma_i^{2}=\theta$. What I am wondering is: in general, given the rearrangement of the LL function derivative in my previous comment, would the the LL function derivative be zero at the parameter for any valid choice of $\sigma_i^{2}$ function?

Comment: if I were to choose $\sigma_j^{2}=e^{\theta}$ (I think this would this be a valid function for the covariance as it would always be positive for all positive $\theta$?) then the LL derivative would be -0.5 at the parameter (I think?). Maybe there is something completely wrong in my understanding of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the parameter"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "at the true parameter value". If a particular parameter value $\theta=\theta_0$ produces a sample of the random variable $z$, then we ought to be able to estimate $\theta_0$ by maximizing the LL function (i.e. by finding the zero derivative point), the MLE as you mentioned. So, now if $\sigma_j^{2}=e^{\theta}$ is a valid covariance function (let's say for a distribution of only positive $\theta$), then the derivative of the LL won't be zero at $\theta_0$, I think?

Comment: @JNL : Of course, the derivative $L'(\theta_0)$ of the log-likelihood function $L$ at the true value $\theta_0$ of the parameter will almost never be zero. That derivative, $L'(\theta_0)$, is a random variable whose values depend on the sample values $z_1,\dots,z_m$, and in problems like this $L'(\theta_0)$ will take the zero value only with probability $0$. On the other hand, you will have $L'(\hat\theta_m)=0$, where $\hat\theta_m$ is the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE).

Comment: Previous comment continued: But the root $\hat\theta_m$ of $L'$ is -- not the constant $\theta_0$ -- but a random variable, whose values depend on the sample values $z_1,\dots,z_m$. The MLE $\hat\theta_m$ will **almost never be equal to** the true value $\theta_0$ of the parameter. Instead, as in the particular setting considered in my answer, the MLE $\hat\theta_m$ will, under suitable conditions **converge** to the true value $\theta_0$ of the parameter in probability (and even almost surely) as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: @JNL : Is the matter now clear to you?

Comment: ah! I understand now. The derivative will only be zero at the max likelihood estimate (well, that is how we calculate the estimate anyway, by finding the point where the derivative is zero), and this estimate is expected to converge to the parameter value asymptotically. My mistake in understanding was that I had thought the derivative would be zero for the true parameter value. Thanks for the explanation, appreciate it! :-)

Comment: can I please ask for your thoughts on another question I posted here on the singularity of the Fisher information matrix and the existence of unbiased estimators (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448546/singular-fisher-information-matrix-and-existence-of-unbiased-estimators)? I still haven't found an answer to this or found out where I might be going wrong.